# problems in building xml using Nokogiri in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

I need to build the following xml data

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:description7a.services.chrome.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest>
         <urn:accountInfo number="test" secret="test" country="US" language="en" behalfOf="test"/>
         <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level-->
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:styleId>test</urn:styleId>
         <urn:switch>ShowAvailableEquipment</urn:switch>
         <urn:includeMediaGallery>Both</urn:includeMediaGallery>
      </urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using the following code to build it

```
def self.xml_build(style_id,number,secret,behalfOf)
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.send("soapenv:Envelope"){
      xml.send("soapenv:Header")
        xml.send("soapenv:Body") {
          xml.send("urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest"){
            xml.send("urn:accountInfo")("number"=>"#{number}" "secret"=>"#{secret}" "country"=>"US" "language"=>"en" "behalfOf"=>"#{behalfOf}")
            xml.send("urn:styleId"){xml.text "#{style_id}"}
            xml.send("urn:switch"){xml.text "ShowAvailableEquipment"}
            xml.send("urn:includeMediaGallery"){xml.text "Both"}
            }
          } 
        }
    end
    file_test=File.new("dummy_file", 'w')
    file_test.puts builder.to_xml
    builder.to_xml
end
```

I am getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: /home/aravind/Documents/dev/nthat/app/models/carinfo.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '}'
...   xml.send("urn:accountInfo")("number"=>"#{number}" "secret...
...                               ^
/home/aravind/Documents/dev/nthat/app/models/carinfo.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
...d("urn:accountInfo")("number"=>"#{number}" "secret"=>"#{secr...
...                               ^
/home/aravind/Documents/dev/nthat/app/models/carinfo.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
...number"=>"#{number}" "secret"=>"#{secret}" "country"=>"US" "...
...                               ^
/home/aravind/Documents/dev/nthat/app/models/carinfo.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
...ecret"=>"#{secret}" "country"=>"US" "language"=>"en" "behalf...
...                               ^
/home/aravind/Documents/dev/nthat/app/models/carinfo.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
...}" "country"=>"US" "language"=>"en" "behalfOf"=>"#{behalfOf}...
...                               ^
/home/aravind/Documents/dev/nthat/app/models/carinfo.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
..." "language"=>"en" "behalfOf"=>"#{behalfOf}")
```

Also I am not sure how to build this part of the xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:description7a.services.chrome.com">
```

Comment: The error points straight at the problem. Line 27 .. what looks different about that line compared to the similar ones below it? :)

Comment: `("number"=>"#{number}" "secret"=>"#{secret}" "country"=>"US" "language"=>"en" "behalfOf"=>"#{behalfOf}")`

This is the line. My doubt is how to `<urn:accountInfo number="test" secret="test" country="US" language="en" behalfOf="test"/>` build such an xml

Comment: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html

Comment: I have already seen that. I am not sure why you are pointing that.

Comment: I was trying to point you gently towards the fact your problem is because you had the syntax `something()()`, which clearly isn't valid Ruby, hence the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will generate your xml:

```
require 'nokogiri'    
def self.xml_build(style_id,number,secret,behalfOf)    
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.send("soapenv:Envelope", 'xmlns:soapenv' => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 'xmlns:urn' => "urn:description7a.services.chrome.com"){
      xml.send("soapenv:Header")
        xml.send("soapenv:Body") {
          xml.send("urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest"){
          xml.send("urn:accountInfo", "number"=>"#{number}", "secret"=>"#{secret}", "country"=>"US", "language"=>"en", "behalfOf"=>"#{behalfOf}")
            xml.comment('You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level')
            xml.comment('Optional:')
            xml.send("urn:styleId"){xml.text "#{style_id}"}
            xml.send("urn:switch"){xml.text "ShowAvailableEquipment"}
            xml.send("urn:includeMediaGallery"){xml.text "Both"}
            }
          } 
        }
     end
end
puts xml_build('test', 'test', 'test', 'test').to_xml
#=> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:description7a.services.chrome.com">
#=>   <soapenv:Header/>
#=>   <soapenv:Body>
#=>     <urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest>
#=>       <urn:accountInfo number="test" secret="test" country="US" language="en" behalfOf="test"/>
#=>       <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level-->
#=>       <!--Optional:-->
#=>       <urn:styleId>test</urn:styleId>
#=>       <urn:switch>ShowAvailableEquipment</urn:switch>
#=>       <urn:includeMediaGallery>Both</urn:includeMediaGallery>
#=>     </urn:VehicleDescriptionRequest>
#=>   </soapenv:Body>
#=> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The exception you were seeing was due to how you were trying to create the attributes of the accountInfo node. Note that the attributes should be passed as arguments to the send method:

```
xml.send("urn:accountInfo", "number"=>"#{number}", "secret"=>"#{secret}", "country"=>"US", "language"=>"en", "behalfOf"=>"#{behalfOf}")
```

The same can be done to get the attributes on the Envelope node:

```
xml.send("soapenv:Envelope", 'xmlns:soapenv' => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 'xmlns:urn' => "urn:description7a.services.chrome.com")
```

Finally, to get the comments, use the `comment` method:

```
xml.comment('You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level')
xml.comment('Optional:')
```